# Basic and extended regular expression

Tags: regular-expression

I have a question: How to search a string using a basic regular expression in Vi editor? How about using extended regular expression in Vi editor?. Is it a real difference between basic regular expression and extended regular expression? They have different syntaxes but the algorithm is the same. What is the logically correct answer for this question?

Comment: What do you mean by basic and extended regexp? Are you talking about very magic mode?

Comment: Vim uses its own dialect of regexes. See `:help regexp` for detailed information that should answer your question and then some.

(Note, your question is too "fuzzy", and so I won't even try to give a full answer.)

Comment: Welcome to our site @MadScientists! For now your question is pretty unclear and I'm not sure someone can answer it. I think you should read the help as Karl suggested and also have a look at [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2268/1841) which could be useful to you. Then please edit your question so that it is easier to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: As Karl mentions Vim has it's own dialect. It almost surely evolved from BRE/ERE, though, by way of "traditional" vi given the BRE/ERE bits that remain today and based on some evidence that I mention in my answer to a question on this site: [Traditional vi and it's regular expressions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13598/traditional-vi-and-its-regular-expressions). All that said I'm not sure whether I'm actually addressing any of your question or not! It needs clarifying as other mentioned.