# Regex flavor in vim for doing substitutions

Tags: vimrc, regular-expression

I'm having a hard time writing regexes in vim -- it seems everything I try either requires an escape character or isn't supported. For example, I have a SQL statement that includes something like:

```
max(if(s.name like 'iTunes' and completion_date is not null, 'Complete', if(s.name like 'iTunes', 'X', null))) iTunes,
max(if(s.name like 'amazon' and completion_date is not null, 'Complete', if(s.name like 'Amazon', 'X', null))) Amazon
```

And I want to change it from `'itunes'` to `'%%itunes%%'` for the like statement to work. My first attempt was:

- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to highlight the lines I want to replace
- `s/'([a-z]+)'/'%%\1%%'`

To which I get:

> E486: Pattern not found: '([a-z]+)'

How would I enter in that regex, and is there a good place to learn about regex use in vim (specifically what's supported and what needs to be escaped)?

---

**Update**: even though it's a bit dry, the docs are great here for a comprehensive reference: [`pattern`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html). And the regex that worked was:

- `s/'\(\a\{2,}\)'/'%%\1%%'/g`

A few notes:

- There is no `[a-z]`. Need to use [`\l`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cl) (lowercase) or or [`\a`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Ca) (lower or uppercase) instead.
- Capturing groups need to be escaped on both sides: `\(...\)` and then reference it with `\1`.
- For a repetition, the first part needs to be escaped: `\{2,}`

Basically, just keep the reference handy as there are a lot of real quirky things here!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the Vim flavor of regex is a bit different from what you'll find in languages such as Python or Perl.

In particular, you need to escape the sets of parens that mark a group. Also, the `+` to repeat one or more.

But `[a-z]` itself works as expected. (Not that there's anything wrong with `\a`, which is in many senses better... But I just wanted to point out that a character range such as `[a-z]` will work in Vim regexes.)

This will work:

```
s/'\([a-z]\+\)'/'%%\1%%'/
```

But will it match only lowercase letters? Well, it depends! If you have either `set ignorecase` or `set smartcase`, then it will match either lowercase or uppercase words, since either of those will make this regex match case-insensitively.

You might want to look into the [`\v`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv) modifier for the "verymagic" mode, which make regexes work closer to how they work in other languages. Parens and `+` are now metacharacters by default.

```
s/\v'([a-z]+)'/'%%\1%%'/
```

You can also force `'ignorecase'` behavior by including a [`\c`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cc) anywhere in your regex (or make it match case exactly with `\C`.)

One quite unique feature of Vim regexes is that you can use [`\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) and [`\ze`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cze) to mark the start and end of the actual match. So you can replace a word within quotes without capture groups.

```
s/\v\c'\zs[a-z]+\ze'/%%&%%/
```

There are many more features of the Vim regex engine. Hopefully these pointers here will get you started. The docs are really good, so read those too.

Answer (score 1):

Vim regex [are Basic Regular Expression](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13600/786) which predate PCRE. IMHO the former are better for text edition and the latter for scripting. I’ve noticed that often I use search and replace with literal characters, for example, when I need to find `myFunction(`, and Vim’s default behaviour is good for that. So that’s why you need to escape things like `(` and `)`.

But if you need to write complicated regexes you can change the characters that need to be escaped in scripts and in runtime! I know at first it is confusing, but now I think it is an awesome feature. See `:help magic` for details, and read [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2279/786), it changed my mind about BRE and helped me understand the `magic` thing.